# Can't do reverse SSH tunneling in LOCAL network

Tags: ssh

I want to do reverse SSH tunneling in Local Network.

Machine_A = 192.168.0.3 running SSH server behind firewall,
Machine_B = 192.168.0.5 is allowed to access SSH server and is behind the firewall.
Machine_C = 192.168.0.2 can't connect B or C directly

192.168.0.3 has two users: userB, userC i.e., userB can access 192.168.0.3 but userC can't.

All machines are running LINUX. How can Machine_C achieve SSH connection using reverse SSH ? Do I need to enable Port forwarding in ROUTER?

In Machine_B I have to use: ssh -R 12345:localhost:22 _____? from Machine_C :  ssh  -p 12345  _______?

Answer (score 0):

On Machine_B

```
ssh -g -L 12345:localhost:22 Machine_A
```

On Machine_C

```
ssh -p 12345 Machine_B
```

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I asked the question wrong. Actually I want to establish reverse SSH tunnel where A,B both are behind firewall  and A blocks all incoming  request from C but allows OUTGOING connection.  Sorry for inconvenience.